# Router speed not even close

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem

My laptop which has an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 downloads at about 27Mbps.  My router is a Belkin N150 (Model F9K1001v3).  And I have a Motorola Surfboard SB6141, which supports up to 300Mbps.  My internet connection with Time Warner is 200Mbps.  I should be getting 150 max, right?  Even when I move the laptop close to the router I am getting the same rate.  Wired, I get 100Mbps.

I have made the following changes to the router so far:

1. Changed channel to 11.
2. Disabled Protected Mode.
3. Disabled WMM/QoS.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

A lot of factors also play a role, such as:

- network latency,
- actual wifi protocol in use (a, b, g, n, ...),
- network limits at the serving-side,
- hardware limits on your side (bus, hdd),
- practical router limits (as opposed to theoretical limits: Google with your router specs for real performance statistics to get an idea),
- other traffic on the router,
- percentages of package collisions,
- cable quality or radiographic noise (babyphone, microwave, etc.),
- and so on.

So you see it is really difficult to determine the weakest link. Check each element or link in your chain of devices and components as much as isolated as possible and use tools as ping and traceroute while downloading to get an idea where it goes wrong.

Also see [this link](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/speedtests/a/network-speed.htm) for some more info and suggestions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  Network latency is low, I'm using n protocol, network limits at server side do not apply since I get 100Mbps wired, hardware limits don't apply, practical router limits don't apply, other traffic on router doesn't apply, package collisions don't apply, radiographic noise doesn't apply either.  Something must be misconfigured somewhere, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: [Belkin itself](http://www.belkin.com/router-speed/) reports a maximum of 67 Mbps wireless. Probably in lab conditions (yes, there is radio interference in your home too). Considering [network overhead](http://www.cwnp.com/wi-fi-overhead-part-1-sources-of-overhead/), 27 Mbps isn't that bad. Googling for your router, I see more people complaining about "slow" speeds. I suggest to replace your router by one you can borrow for a moment and see if that makes a difference. Also try connecting you router directly to your ISP modem; see how that goes.